# How can I make a variable static (or "global") in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, static, global-variables

I want to make my variable static or "global" - so the same effect as static in .NET; every session that accesses it gets the same result, and if one session modifies it it affects everyone else too.

How can I achieve this in Classic ASP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have a variable that is accessible application wide, you can use the application object. Be sure to use [Application.Lock/Unlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184.aspx) to prevent any problems.

```
Application.Lock
Application("MyVariable") = "SomeValue"
Application.Unlock
```

Answer (score 7):

using a session variable

```
Session("myVariableName") = "my new value"
```

the scope will be the user...

if you want to wide the scope to ALL users that are in the website, then you use an Application variable

```
Application("myVariableName") = "my new value"
```

you can reset or handle this in the global.asa file as well

This is a common thing to do:

**global.asa** file:

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">

Sub Application_OnStart
  Application("visitors") = 0
End Sub

Sub Session_OnStart
  Application.Lock
  Application("visitors") = Application("visitors") + 1
  Application.UnLock
End Sub

Sub Session_OnEnd
  Application.Lock
  Application("visitors") = Application("visitors") - 1
  Application.UnLock
End Sub

</script>
```

**default.asp** file:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>There are <%response.write(Application("visitors"))%> online now!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No I don't want session variables - that is scoped per session!

Comment: if you want to wide up the scope to all users, use the Application variable as I specify in my answer :) this is how we accomplish "How many users" are in the website for example ;)