# Using a dictionary object in application scope in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, dictionary, scope, scripting.dictionary

Following up from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909808/how-can-i-make-a-variable-static-or-global-in-classic-asp) does anyone know how I can use a dictionary object in application scope in Classic ASP? You cannot use **Scripting.Dictionary** - if you try you will see something similar to the following:

```
Application object error 'ASP 0197 : 80004005'
Disallowed object use /xxx.asp, line 2. Cannot add object with apartment model behavior to the application intrinsic object.
```

I found [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20061026092009/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=129) on (good ol') 4GuysFromRolla but it points to [Microsoft's free Lookup Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/server/downloads/lkuptbl.asp) and a [free Dictionary Component from Caprock Consulting](http://www.caprockconsulting.com/comsoftware.asp) - both of which are dead links.

The article clearly explains *why* you can't use the **Scripting.Dictionary** in application scope, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a free alternative or where I might find a copy of the old components that 4GuysFromRolla mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to download the Dictionary Component from Caprock Consulting using this link: http://web.archive.org/web/20000619122506/http://www.caprockconsulting.com/data/CaprockDCT.zip

Answer (score 2):

I have the LookupTable-component and can provide it to you if interested.

However, I have notived that you can use .NET HashTable in application-scope which might be useful for you.

just do this:

```
<object id="YOUR_VAR_NAME" progid="System.Collections.HashTable" runat="Server" scope="Application"></object>
```

this will give you a global, application-wide HashTable-object.

Beware of modifying this to heavily though, I have problems with memoryleaks where eventually the applications session-handling gets unreliable (doesn't invoke SessionStart properly)

Comment: Actually, it's possible to create a scripting.dictionary in the application-scope aswell: <object id="YOUR_VAR_NAME" progid="Scripting.Dictionary" runat="Server" scope="Application"></object> add that to your global.asa

Comment: +1 Just what I needed. Thank you. Is there some drawback with using the Dictionary as a global object as with the HashTable?

Comment: @rcdmk I think I saw the same memory leak tendencies with the Dictionary as well, so I would advise against modifying the dictionary heavily.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just use it to create a global dict and populate it on global.asa with some texts I use to localize the site.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and ended up feeding the application variable with the content of my dictionary and added

```
    for each obj in application.Contents
        if Left(obj,6) = "urlLog" then
            application.Contents.Remove(obj)
        end if
    next
```

to kill all the application variables in the global.asa on application.end ( you could also use the `Application.Contents.RemoveAll` but i heard there was som issue with it leaving some variable up and causing memory leak even tho i could net find any solid source to prove it ...

anyway is the Caprock dictionary working for you ?