# Storing a Dictionary or Arraylist in IIS Application variables

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, asp-classic, global.asa

I'm trying to store a Dictionary in the IIS Application variables using Global.ASA however I read this isnt possible due to something related to threading and dictionaries.

Since then Im trying to store an ArrayList, however this seems to fail too.

```
DIM LanguageArray
set LanguageArray   = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
-- Populate Array List
Application("LanguageArray") = LanguageArray.Synchronized(LanguageArray)
```

I have a fairly basic setup, I declare the array list, create it and then populate it and finally try put it into the Application object.  I read that Synchronized returns a thread safe wrapper and an example I saw did this however i'm pretty sure this is wrong.

I'm at a loss of what to do now, can ArrayLists even go into Application variables? If so is my call to Synchronized incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Synchronized` but if it's returning a thread-safe COM object, shouldn't you be assigning it with the `Set` keyword?

Comment: @Bond I just tried SET Application("LanguageArray") = LanguageArray.Synchronized(LanguageArray) but that didnt work either.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909877/using-a-dictionary-object-in-application-scope-in-classic-asp) question? One of the comments suggests it is possible to use a `Dictionary` object if done with the `<object>` tag. Also, one of the answers shows how to use a .NET `HashTable`, again using the `<object>` tag.

Comment: I wouldn't, better off pulling it out of a DB or file.  If you do though, don't forget to use `Application.Lock`/`Unlock` when you're updating it.

Comment: @ZeeTee I have to do it this way to improve the performance. Not the best solution I know. And I'm only setting the collection once from Global.Asa after that it will never be updated so no need to worry about locking it.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish You should test it against pulling the same data from a DB and see which has better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bond for the link to this previous post : [Using a dictionary object in application scope in Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909877/using-a-dictionary-object-in-application-scope-in-classic-asp)

The solution was to use an  Tag like so

```
<object id="YOUR_VAR_NAME" progid="Scripting.Dictionary" runat="Server"    scope="Application"></object>
```