# Does classic ASP have an equivalent to the #if DEBUG statement from C#?

Tags: c#, vbscript, asp-classic, jscript

In C#, I can say

```cs
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("we are in debug mode");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("we are in release mode");
#endif
```

This is handy for managing things that need to be different between debug and release builds, e.g. connection strings. Is there anything like this available in classic ASP?

Comment: No *(Just set your own `debug` flag)*. Next!...

Comment: there are a number of ways to "inspect" the server name -- that lets you change depending on environment.  (eg if localhost output deug info)

Comment: @Hogan not really the same thing though is it?

Comment: @Lankymart kinda is I think -- debug in C# is defined in the environemnt just like the name

Comment: @Hogan kind of, it's just a flag though that is set by the Configuration.

Comment: @Lankymart in C# you could use `#if HOGAN_DEBUG` and it would work the same way.  the `DEBUG` is just one that by default is set up in the build files

Comment: @Hogan yep, that is true. But like I said Classic ASP doesn't have anything like that. These types of preprocessor directives change the behaviour of the compiler, Classic ASP isn't compiled code. So the closest you can get to it is build a persisted Application variable as a flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

But that doesn't mean you can't build your own debug flag then use that. There are various ways to do this using `Application` or `Session` variables.

You could then use them something like;

```vb
'Application variable should have been set in the global.asa file.
Dim debug: debug = (Application("debug") = True)
If debug Then
  'Output some debug information.
Else
  'Release mode.
End If
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [How can I make a variable static (or “global”) in Classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/909808/692942)

Comment: @Hogan not really it's not a preprocessor directive or anything like that. Also, Classic ASP uses VBScript by default which is a scripting language not a compiled one like .Net languages.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at, we are talking about Classic ASP not .Net *(VB.Net, C#, ASP.Net, MVC etc.)*.

Comment: @Hogan Not sure what we are arguing about to be honest, think i'll leave it there. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Agreed -- you answer is excellent and exactly what is needed IMO

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks! Just curious though - what's the colon for in the `Dim` statement? I've never seen that syntax in VB before...

Comment: @ekolis [VBScript, purpose of colon?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1144914)

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, I totally forgot about that silly feature of VB!